# iframe background image showing fine in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, cross-browser

Why IE not showing BG mage like firefox in Iframe?

I do not have access of iframed page.

any CSS or javascript solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As well as adding the CSS style `background-color:transparent;` to the iframe document's body element, you will also need to add the `allowtransparency` attribute to the iframe element in the containing document.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072(VS.85).aspx for more information.

If you can't modify the iframe's document then you are out of luck.  Maybe there's another source you can use for the data that provides it in a different format such as XML or JSON?

Comment: i do not have code access of iframe url page.so it's not possible, right.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do it yourself.  Maybe you can contact the service provider and ask them to add the attribute?  Or maybe they provide the data in a different format?

Comment: @Andy E - Is there any javascript way?

Comment: AFAIK, not any javascript way that wouldn't violate the cross-domain policy.  You could use a PHP script that either scraped the HTML to harvest the data or output just the ticker HTML with the additional transparency CSS style but of course that might not be an acceptable method of retrieving the data in the eyes of the data owner and it will of course increase the overheads on and requests to your web server per page viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code to the document that's included by the iframe: `background-color:transparent;`

Comment: i can't give style to page which is in iframe