# IFrame background transparent in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, transparent

So i have this iFrame with the class .transparentbg:

```
.transparantbg{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but not in IE...

Help please?

Greetings

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe background image showing fine in Firefox but not in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056302/iframe-background-image-showing-fine-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Add allowTransparency="true" to your iframe

```
<IFRAME ID="Frame1" SRC="whatever.htm" allowTransparency="true">
```

For whatever.htm add `background:transparent` to its `body` tag.

```
<body style="background:transparent">
```

Comment: great! this works perfectly for IE8 but i'm still having problems with IE7 its still showing a white background in place of transparent any ideas.??...

Comment: Yes, live with the fact that a very small percentage of your users will see a white background instead of a transparent one.

Comment: ah, after two days, i found this solution. many many many thanks to both you guys

Comment: If anyone is seeing further issues, I'm finding that in IE8, when an existing iframe changes it's source, the html tag within it must be styled as well.

Comment: appears IE9 doesn't require the `allowTransparency="true"` part.