# IE8 css style table width and alignment woes

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, alignment

http://techmobile.com/defaultIE8TEST.html#footer

Looks like my table under the hometext div is jacked in IE8 works fine (according to browsershots dot org IE7's body footer is shot too).

ie8
http://browsershots.org/screenshots/6d7e47f9d7a763a5942211235691915c

The table width is not stretching far enough and sets off the other graphics, is my summation of the problem. But what CSS fixes it?

I added the last part #wrapper #hometext. Otherwise, very few <strike>nuggets</strike> in IE8's CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* IE 8 CSS Document */


/* top area */

#top #phone {
    width: 110px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#wrapper #headermenu ul.menu li {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#wrapper #hometxt {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0 solid #000</b>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

`style="table-layout: fixed;"` to the table tag.

Comment: hmmm well it's not the table width . . . i've checked all the divs

Comment: Ok that did fix the table but it didn't fix the boxes. So the table width was not throwing off the boxes [link] http://techmobile.com/defaultnomoescroll5.html [/link]

Comment: @ScottJaxon could you provide the image you want to do

Comment: the bottom blue boxes aren't rendering correctly in IE8. As seen here: http://browsershots.org/screenshots/dac3c2ea6c3e603968c3feeb3a743d2b

Comment: ok it was overflow issue: overflow: hidden - now there is a white box showing around the PaPal button only in IE8.

Comment: got it: made the background transparent <body style="background:transparent"> and more from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133998/iframe-background-transparent-in-ie