# Telerik Controls - Background Image not showing in IE8

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer-8, telerik

I have a web Application having some telerik controls.

i have following telerik Control :

```
telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" Behavior="Close" VisibleStatusbar="false" VisibleTitlebar="true"
        InitialBehavior="None" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"  Modal="True" Overlay="True"  
        Behaviors="None" Height="640px" Width="900px" Skin="Telerik" EnableShadow="true" OnClientResizeEnd="SetWindowBehavior" >
        <Windows>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindowTreeview" Title="Careplan Tree" runat="server" Modal="true"
                OnClientClose="OnClientClose" Behaviors="Close" BackColor="Transparent" DestroyOnClose="false"
                NavigateUrl="MainTreeContainer.aspx" BorderStyle="None" Visible="True" VisibleStatusbar="False"
                VisibleTitlebar="False" Width="900px" Height="640px" Animation="Fade" AutoSize="False"
                AnimationDuration="1000" Opacity="100">  </telerik:RadWindow>
            <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" CssClass="defaultWindow" Width="900px" Height="640px" AutoSize="False" 
                runat="server" Modal="true" Behaviors="None" Overlay="true" NavigateUrl="~/Terms.aspx"  OnClientClose="OnClientClose1" >
            </telerik:RadWindow>

             <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow3"  CssClass="defaultWindow" MinWidth="900px" MinHeight="640px" AutoSize="False" 
                runat="server" Modal="true" Behaviors="None" Overlay="true" NavigateUrl="~/Privacy.aspx"  OnClientClose="OnClientClose3" >
            </telerik:RadWindow>

        </Windows>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

i am opening an aspx form in `RadWindowTreeview` Radwindow .. i have overridden some telerik CSS  like following:

```
.rwWindowContent, .rwExternalContent
        {
            border-style: groove !important;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-image: url('background.jpg') !important;
            border-color: GhostWhite;
        }
```

but the background image doesn't display in IE8 only.. it displays well in Mozila, chrome,safari and IE9.. but not display only in IE8..

any suggestions ?
thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are not transparent in IE8 and below, see here:
[IFrame background transparent in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133998/iframe-background-transparent-in-ie)
Apply this attribute in the **OnClientShow event** of the control:
**sender.get_contentFrame()** is a reference to the iframe you need, where sended is the first argument the handler receives.