# IE7 not showing transparent background in an iframe

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm able to get transparent background for an iframe for IE8 and firefox. But i'm having problem in IE7 it keeps showing up a white background!!
this is what i'm doing :-

```
<IFRAME id="". ... ... ..allowTransparency="true">
```

and this is what i'm writing in the css of the iframe body:-

```
<body style="background:transparent">
```

refrences :- [Iframe background transparent in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133998/iframe-background-transparent-in-ie)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056302/iframe-background-image-showing-fine-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie

Comment: IFrame is a really messy stuff. Can you provide some links to specify your problem. Please put it up on Fiddle if its not a security issue at your place to do so??